# Neo4j community detection algorithm : louvain

Tags: neo4j

I want to apply Louvain algorithm on a social network graph for realizing a project about defining probable cases of COVID-19 (contact tracing); the graph contains relationships between a set of persons (nodes); relationships contain distance as property.
two persons can have multiple relationships so it means that these persons were in distance in different time instances.

Can Louvain allow me to obtain communities where each community will have the nearest persons together? Louvain can understand that relationships' weights are not the strength of a relationship but the distance.

Comment: Someone has an answer please !?

Comment: I want to use Louvain for clustering a large-scale network. How can I identify the number of the required clusters since there is no parameter that can be configured for this purpose in the algorithm built in Neo4j?